# Any Septuagint (LXX) audio book available online?

Tags: bible, bible-translation

Searching for a complete audio of Septuagint - Ancient, not Modern Greek translation.

Is it available anywhere online?

I seek audio in ancient Greek, no matter if it's Erasmian or Reuchlinian pronunciation.

Comment: Audio in ancient Greek, or audio of a translation of the Septuagint in a modern language (Russian, English, etc.) ?

Comment: I seek audio in ancient Greek, no matter if it's Erasmian or Reuchlinian pronunciation.

Comment: I think [Mick Jagger](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0qnt5rTCoo&t=59) might have one.

Comment: link broken "This video isn't available anymore" regarding : "I think Mick Jagger might have one. – user46876 Sep 15, 2020 at 7:11"

Answer (score 2):

Audio CD is available here: [The English Translation of the Septuagint Bible Online](http://www.ecmarsh.com/lxx/index_old.html) and [here](http://www.ecmarsh.com/Septuagint.htm).

It also has ***The Translation of the Old Testament***, Including the Apocrypha.
Compiled from the Translation by Sir Lancelot C. L. Brenton 1851.

Has History & Reference Books available also.

Comment: link broken : https://www.ecmarsh.com/Septuagint.htm "Sorry, you have been blocked
You are unable to access ecmarsh.com"

Comment: link broken : https://www.ecmarsh.com/lxx/index_old.html "Sorry, you have been blocked
You are unable to access ecmarsh.com"

Answer (score -1):

You can listen to it here:
https://live.bible.is/bible/ELLAPE/MAT/1?audio_type=audio

God bless you!
Jakub

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: if that is matthew and new testament , how is that septuagint ? genesis 1 link : https://live.bible.is/bible/ELLAPE/GEN/1?audio_type=audio